# Mathematical problem - Set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

there is set A = {a,b,c,d,e,f}.

Problem is:

{d,b,f,a,e,c} ∈ A

is it T or F and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, I took $\subset$ as  $\in$.

Answer (score 1):

It is false.

You have $\{d,b,f,a,e,c\}\subset A$, but not  $\{d,b,f,a,e,c\}\in A$.

The symbol "$\in$" can only be used for elements of $A$. Namely, $a\in A$, $b\in A$, ...

In fact, not only $\{d,b,f,a,e,c\}\subset A$, but also $A=\{d,b,f,a,e,c\}$.

Comment: Well, what if $A=a$? Is $\{d,b,f,a,e,c\}\in A$ then?

Comment: You haven't addressed the possibility of $A$ being one of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ or $f$.

Comment: Well, in that case, being $A$ and element of $A$ , it is true, but the general statement asked to be true o false, is false.

Comment: In which situation is relevant to consider a set as a element of itself? I know that it leads to some paradox in some situations, for instance Russell Paradox

Answer (score 0):

For $a\in A$ to be true, $a$ must be an element of $A$.

In this case, each of $a, b, c, d, e$ and $f$ are elements of $A$. But, $\{a,b, c, s, e, f\} = \{d,b,f,a,e,c\}$ is not an element of $A$. Actually, it is $A$ itself ($\{d,b,f,a,e,c\} = A$).

To clarify, $a$ is an element (could be another set or whatever) and $\{a\}$ is a set containing $a$. So, $a\in \{a\}$ and $a \neq \{a\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you expressed it wrongly it's false because if $\{d, b, f, a, e, c\} \in A$ then $\{d, b, f, a, e, c\} = x$ for $x$ being one of $a, b, c, d, e, f$, that since $\{b, d, f, a, e, c\} = A$ such a case is disallowed.

The reason it's disallowed is by the axiom of regularity and axiom schema of separation. Suppose $A\in A$, then you could construct a new set (from axiom schema of separation) $B = \{x\in A: x = A\} = \{A\}$. As having only one element it would (by the axiom of regularity) be disjoint from it's member, that is $B \cap A = \emptyset$, but we've already assumed that both $A$ and $B$ contains $A$.